# How to convert an array of objects into array of strings in Angular to display in a Angular material table?

Tags: angular, postgresql, spring-boot, angular-material

I am developing a CRUD application of Employee management system. I use Angular, Angular Material, Spring Boot and PostgreSQL for this. There are two tables Employee and Skills in database which are mapped using Many to Many mapping. Here I am retrieving data to a table in the frontend. But the skill field is retrieved as Objects. But I need them as strings to display in the table.

This is how my data is like.

```
{
    "id": 7,
    "name": "User1",
    "dob": "2021-04-02T18:30:00.000+00:00",
    "email": "user1@abc.com",
    "skills": [
        {
            "id": 6,
            "skill_name": "Backend Developer"
        },
        {
            "id": 7,
            "skill_name": "Frontend Developer"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is what I receive in the table.

```
Name      DOB        Email               Skills
User2   1995-11-21  user1@gmail.com     [object Object]
User2   1995-07-04  user2@gmail.com     [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
User3   2021-04-03  user3@abc.com       [object Object],[object Object]
```

This is the relevant part in html file.

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
<table mat-table [dataSource]="employees" >

  <!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name" sticky>
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- DOB Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="dob">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> DOB </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.dob | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Email Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Email </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.email}} </td>
  </ng-container>

<!--   skills Column-->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="skills">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Skills </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.skills}} </td>
  </ng-container>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call a method that does the job. Something like this:

```
getSkills(element: any): string {
    let skills = "";

    element.skills.forEach(skill => {
        skills += skill.skill_name + ", ";
    }

    return skills;
}


<!--   skills Column-->
<ng-container matColumnDef="skills">
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Skills </th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{getSkills(element)}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

You has two options

1.-Iterate over skills

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
   <span *ngFor="skill of element.skills;let last=last">
     {{skill.skill_name}}{{!last?' - ':''}}</span>
</td>
```

2.-add a new property, e.g. skillsTxt with the name of skills

When you has the data

```
   this.data.forEach(x=>{
     x.skillsTxt=x.skills.map(s=>s.skill_name).Join(" - ");
   })
```

And use in td

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> 
   {{element.skillsTxt}}
</td>
```